# Binary expansions of dyadic rationals in $[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers, binary

[image]

Completely stuck on this exercise! Hints and a starting point would be greatly appreciated. Nor do I see why is $x \in [ 0,1] \setminus D$ do not have $2$ binary expansions.

Comment: Hint: Prove the contra-positive. Assume a number does not have those two binary expansions and prove it is not a dyadic rational. Also, $x\in [0,1)$ clearly from the definition of D, because $\frac{k}{2^n} < 1$.

Comment: Sorry i will probably need more than that as i am struggling to see the general direction of the proof

Comment: Actually $0$ which seems to be included in your definition of dyadic rationals does not have two expansions, but other than that exception, the result is correct.

Comment: Oh, I think I may have misinterpreted the problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: $\frac{1}{2^i}+\frac{1}{2^{i+1}}+\cdots=\frac1{2^{i-1}}$.

Also dyadic rationals have a terminating binary expansion.

So you can trade in the last $1$ in the terminating representation for a $0$ in that place followed by a tail of all $1$s.

E.g., (binary representations): $.00101=.00100111111111...$

Comment: Thanks i understand this but writing this as a formal proof is harder than the describing the solution

Comment: Yes, it probably is, but it is also good to strengthen your mathematical writing skills!  :-)