# Whether a real number is a dyadic rational iff its binary expansion terminates?

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, binary

In self-studying a textbook on computability theory, I found that many of the exercises depend on the following factlet:

> A dyadic rational is a rational number whose denominator is a power of two, i.e. a rational number of the form $\frac{a}{2^b}$. A real number is a dyadic rational if and only if its binary expansion terminates.

I have the following for the forward direction:

> The binary expansion of a number between $0$ and $1$ is of the form
>     \begin{equation*}
>     0.x_1x_2x_3\cdots = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k2^{-k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_k}{2^k}
>   \end{equation*}
>     Suppose a number $0 < x < 1$ has a terminating binary expansion.
>     Then its expansion is of the form $0.x_1\cdots x_k$, where $x_k$ is the last $1$ digit.
>     Then
>     \begin{equation*}
>     x = \frac{x_1}{2^1} + \frac{x_2}{2^2} + \ldots + \frac{x_k}{2^k} = \frac{x_12^{k-1} + x_22^{k-2} + \ldots + x_k}{2^k}
>   \end{equation*}
>     Since this is base-$2$, each $x_i$ must be either $0$ or $1$, whence it follows that the denominator and numerator are integers, and the denominator is a power of two, which means $x$ is a dyadic rational.

For the converse, I have the following idea, but do not have the background to write up a rigorous proof (in particular, I cannot imagine how to deal with the ambiguity of infinite $1$s *versus* infinite $0$s at some point in the expansion):

> Conversely, we must show that if $0 < \frac{a}{2^b} < 1$ is a dyadic rational, then its binary expansion terminates.
>     Every dyadic rational can be represented as the finite sum/product $\left(\frac{1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{1}{2}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{1}{2}$.
>     The binary expansion of the sum of two numbers with terminating binary expansions terminates, same for the product; and it follows that the binary expansion of a dyadic rational terminates.

I have not yet formally tackled (but have vague, possibly incorrect, intuition of) the construction of real numbers, Cauchy convergence and proof by induction (which I gather could be used somehow...), but I need to convince myself of the factlet and its possible pitfalls to continue with the material for the time being (namely, Cantor's diagonalization proofs). Any detailed hints or full-on proofs would be greatly appreciated.

(I have found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/970059/263356) but the hint in the answer seems unhelpful given my lack of background.)

**EDIT**:

> Observe that $a$ is a finite integer, and so can be written as the finite-term sum $x_12^{k-1} + x_22^{k-2} + \ldots + x_k$, where $x_i \in \{0, 1\}$.
>     Since $\frac{a}{2^b} < 1$, it follows that $a < 2^b$.
>     By the definition of binary expansion, $x_1 = 1$, whence $2^{k-1} \le a < 2^b$, and we have $k-1<b$.
>     But $1 \le i \le k$, whence $k-i<b$.
>     Then we can divide each term by $2^b$, obtaining:
>     \begin{equation*}
>     \frac{a}{2^b} = \frac{x_1}{2^{b-k+1}} + \frac{x_2}{2^{b-k+2}} + \ldots + \frac{x_k}{2^b},
>   \end{equation*}
>     which gives us a finite binary expansion; this completes the proof.

Comment: What's $i$ in your bolded statement?

Comment: @columbus8myhw It was the index of each $x_i$ in the binary representation of $a$, and I wanted to demonstrate that $k-i<b$ to make sure that it makes sense to divide each term by $2^b$ and that we obtain the expansion of a number less than $1$. In any case, I saw where I was stuck and got rid of the bolded statement now. Something still doesn't feel right, though. Does the "proof" make sense? Is it rigorous enough?

Comment: Maybe try an example? Like 53/64 or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the binary representation of $\frac{a}{2^k}$ is obtained by shifting the digits (or bits, if you prefer) in the binary representation of $a$ by $k$ places to the right.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question with a sketch of the converse, but I am still stuck with the parts indicated in bold. Would you mind verifying and giving another hint?

Comment: If you need more help with why any natural number has a binary representation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number.

Comment: Thanks, I have actually just removed that part. Sorry, really tired. It remains to show that $k-i<b$, and I am not seeing how at this time. But your answer was really helpful, so I am accepting it. (It won't let me upvote as well until I have 15 rep.)

Comment: Just think of the binary representation as an infinite string of 0s and 1s with a binary point separating the integer part from the fractional part. Multiplication or division by $2$ amounts to shifting the string left or right. If the binary expansion terminates, you can shift it left until you get an integer $a$, and then shift it back to where it came from, say by $k$ places to find that you started with $\frac{a}{2^k}$.